# Pass a c style string to a function C++

Tags: c++, string

I've write a function to reverse a c style string as follows

```
void reverse1(char* str) {
    char* str_end = strchr(str, 0);
    reverse(str, str_end);
}
```

and use this function to print the reversed string

```
void print(char* str) {
    for (int i=0; i!=sizeof(str); ++i) {
        cout << int(*(str+i)) << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

after reversing, the printing result is:
103 110 105 114 116 115 0   0
there will be one extra 0.
I don't know that's why. Hope someone can help me.
Thank you very much!

Comment: `sizeof(str)` is the size of the pointer. I'd recommend just using `std::reverse`.

Comment: I am surprised it works so well, `sizeof(str)` should be just the size of a pointer, and not the length of the string as you would imagine.

Comment: Not sure but maybe it's `\0` and not `0`?

Comment: `sizeof(str)` should have been `strlen(str)`, and a loop should work this way: `for(int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++){ }` from what I see, your program shouldn't work at all.

Comment: @randomp use `strlen( str )` to get a length of string

Comment: @chris I meant origin of char.

Comment: @PLB, I can't see a difference between `'\0'` and `0`

Comment: @borisbn Actually there's not. I just wanted to say that maybe OP calls function that adds `\0` twice, so in the result he gets `\0\0`.

Comment: @borisbn There is no `'\0'` in the question at all. The difference of `'\0'` and `0` is the type, the former is an character. The difference between `\0` and `0` is only visible in strings or arrays of char.

Comment: @PLB Why adding \0 twice? because sizeof ?

Comment: @PLB, oO. I see. You wanted to say `"\0"` and `"0"`. That **is** a difference, of course. Thanks to @harper ))

Answer (score 2):

The expression `sizeof(str)` results to 8 on a 64 bit platform. Therefore you get 8 numbers at standard output.

You should try to use std::string when you program in C++. If you insist to use C style string, you can write the output as:

```
void print(char* str) {
    for (int i=0; i<=strlen(str); ++i) {
        cout << int(*(str+i)) << '\t';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

or

```
void print(char* str) 
{
    do {
        cout << int(*str) << '\t';
    } while (*str++);
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: @qPCR4vir `""` is a zero terminated string and you get one 0.

Comment: Your `i != strlen` version doesn't print the 0/NUL terminator, while the `do { } while ()` version does.

Comment: But in the while you test one past these 0?

Comment: increment str in the while will fix that?

Answer (score 0):

As @harper said

> You should try to use std::string when you program in C++

If so, the easiest way (for me) to print reverse string and to see every character code is

```
std::copy( str.rbegin(), str.rend(), std::ostream_iterator< int >( std::cout, "\t" ) );
```

or

```
std::copy( str.rbegin(), str.rend(), std::ostream_iterator< char >( std::cout, "\t" ) );
```

to see every character itself